# siunitx won't recognise options and new macros

Tags: siunitx

I seem to be having some weird problems with the package `siunitx`.
The package itself works but almost everything I try to add to it in the preamble doesn't work, e.g.:

```
\usepackage[load-configurations={abbreviations,binary}]{siunitx}
```

or

```
\sisetup{load-configurations = abbreviations}
```

or

```
\DeclareSIUnit[per-mode=symbol,per-symbol=p]{\Bps {\byte\per\second}
```

all result in errors of the type:

```
The option `load-configurations' was not declared in package `siunitx', ...
```

or

```
Undefined control sequence
```

Does anyone have an idea what's happening here?

Comment: What version of `siunitx` do you have installed? Add `\listfiles` to your preamble and look at the log, or try `texdoc siunitx` from the command line and see what the PDF says.

Comment: in the `\DeclareSIUnit...` line you missed a `}` after `\Bps`. This could be the reason of the `Undefined control sequence` error.

Comment: Thanks Joseph,
Running this made me realize that the version installed is V1.3a (that's the version that comes with TexLive in ubuntu's repos) while the doc I was looking for is V2.5e.
I was thinking of installing the new version but than I saw that it depends on Latex3 which really doesn't seem like something I'd want to deal with now.

I'll just use \newunit for mow :)

Thanks again